# Where should I put my CSRF token in my Ember app?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a csrf token dumped into a JS variable on window. I have a form that makes AJAX requests (without Ember Data) from the controller. In my request I need to pass along the csrf token. Where are the recommended places to put this token in Ember? Right now I am grabbing it off window but I realize this is bad for testability. My first thought is to register it into the container. I'm pretty new to Ember so any feedback would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @Kingpin2k said, it really doesn't need to be injected into the ember app . You can do it using jquery if you're making ajax call. One simple way is,

1. declare your csrf in server side inside a meta tag content.
2. grab it from the meta tag by its name.
3. use it(e.g. as a **Header**) with jquery(if you want to use it with every ajax request you can do it using `ajaxSetup`).

Something like this.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Add x-csrf-token to all ajax request
  $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending if you are using Ember-cli with modules or just using a global namespace I have different preferences.

If it's global namespace, I prefer just tossing it in the root of the global namespace.

If it's cli, I often have a session service, and I'd just pull it from the window there, or under testing circumstances, allow it to come from another location e.g. `csrf = Testing.csrf || window.csrf` or something along those lines.

Also, in certain circumstances, it really doesn't need to be injected into the ember app.  You can just hook it into jquery to execute on all ajax requests and then not have to think about it in regards to ember itself, since it really isn't related to ember, it's more related to the communication protection being used in jquery with your server.